# Outlook still connects to on-premise Exchange after migration

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office-365, autodiscovery

After migrating to Office 365, our Outlook clients in the office still connect to the on-premise exchange. Mobile and remote clients already work fine.

What's going on? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, you still have an AD record that points clients to your on-premise Exchange during Autodiscovery.

The steps to resolve this can be found in the excellent article [Outlook still trying to connect to old exchange server after moving to Office 365](http://www.itjon.com/outlook-still-trying-to-connect-to-old-exchange-server-after-moving-to-office-365/).

> You can also delete the SCP record altogether using ASDI edit:
>
> 1. Select the “Configuration” naming context
> 2. Drill down to:
>      CN=Services\
>      CN=Microsoft Exchange\
>      CN=*Your Org name*\
>      CN=Administrative Groups\
>      CN=Exchange Administrative Groups\
>      CN=Servers\
>      CN=*Your Server Name*\
>      CN=Protcols\
>      CN=Autodiscover\
> 3. And delete the CN=*Your Server Name* of class serviceConnectionPoint in there

Answer (score 1):

Note that Outlook, even when it uses AutoDiscover, may not properly update a profile to point to the new mailbox in O365.  Older versions of Outlook (prior to OL2016) store values in a profile for on-premises Exchange servers, DCs, and GCs.  If Outlook gets new values from AutoDiscover, it will not clear out or reset those old values.

It is often best to either create a new profile, or to update the existing ones with a tool that knows about migrations.

What version(s) of Outlook are being used today?